# PHP: Execute string as a varible

Tags: php, string

I am trying to echo a string as a variable (`$account_pk`) but it just output's "`$api_key1`" and not the output of the variable, the `1` in `$api_key1` is set when `$key_num` equals to 1.

Part of the code:

```
$key_num = $_POST['keynum'];
$account_pk = '$api_key' . $key_num;
echo $account_pk;
```

UPDATE:
There is not a variable called `$api_key` I need `$account_pk` to combine the string `$api_key` with the variable `$key_num` then find a way to echo the real variable `$api_key1`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what the OP want is

```
$name = "api_key" . $key_num;
echo $$name;
```

Comment: the dark side of php ;)

Answer (score 1):

just use double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
$account_pk = "$api_key" . $key_num;
```

Or like @Devon wrote, no quotes at all. Quotes make only sense if you mix a static string with varialbes, like this:

```
$text = "Hey $name, how are you?";
```

And even in this situation I prefer to write it this way

```
$text = "Hey ".$name." how are you?";
```

because for me it is more readable.

Comment: Or no quotes at all.  Seems unnecessary in this case.

Comment: hey, you're absolutely right

Comment: I would like the variable to become $api_key1 and echo the value of the variable. I've tried your suggestion and it just outputs the number.

Comment: There is not a varible called '$api_key' but there are ones called '$api_key1'

Comment: You can't concatenate a variable name as if it were a string variable. In your case, use an array

Comment: You are wrong, @invisal just solved the question.

Comment: @RichardMcClendon, I don't know about wrong.  I think misunderstood what you were asking...